# Logging in to azure VM using Azure AD credentials

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

This must be so simple, but I am missing something due to missing knowledge in this area;

I want to be able to log in to all our VMs in Azure using Azure AD credentials.
We have our own Azure AD (Only, no on-prem), and I've set up Azure Domain Services.
I then tried to join a VM to our domain. This worked.

However, when I want to add a domain user to a local group, I'm unable to find our domain in the object browser, I can only see the local computer.
I've then tried to add the Virtual Machine Administrator role to myself, but still I can't log in to the VM using AD credentials.

As a last resort I've also tried to install a DC on an Azure VM, to see if this might help, but I'm a bit lost what's the next step then.

Any guidance is really appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Answer Completely stolen from [here](https://superuser.com/questions/982336/how-do-i-add-azure-active-directory-user-to-local-administrators-group)

You can do this via command line! I just had this same issue and after searching and getting nothing but "you can't" from everywhere, I (for giggles and grins) tried this through the command line It will worked.

```
Login to the PC as the Azure AD user you want to be a local admin. This gets the GUID onto the PC.

Log out as that user and login as a local admin user.

Open a command prompt as Administrator and using the command line, add the user to the administrators group. As an example, if I had a user called John Doe, the command would be "net localgroup administrators AzureAD\JohnDoe /add" without the quotes.
```

Log back in as the user and they will be a local admin now

Comment: Thanks, but this means we need to do this per VM? Also, does this require a domain controller and/or Azure AD Domain Services?

Comment: You shouldn't need local DC. But yes, probably need to login to each one. You could script it though with powershell invoke - Login, get guid and pass back, logoff, add to group, etc. There's also another command at the bottom of the link I referenced that you could try out

Answer (score 0):

If you want to login your azure VM with azure ad user, I think you need to create Azure AD domain service and add your VM to the domain. For more details, please refer to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-domain-services/join-windows-vm-template